# Measuring Motor Speed in an analog circuit - (no digital components)

Tags: motor, control-system, motor-controller, pid-controller, closed-loop

I have been searching for several resources on closed-loop analog motor control. Most of them used a tachometer for speed measurement, which makes a lot of sense because the tachometer is analog and has a transfer function in the S-domain.

I have been looking for other alternatives because tachometers are not easy to get in my area, and I have seen some people using potentiometers for closed-loop control. However, the potentiometer is not applicable in my case because it is used only for servo motors.

I have tried to look up using optical encoders for speed measurements, however, the optical encoders function only in the digital domain, and they have no real transfer function in the S-domain.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a cheap DC motor as a generator acting as a tacho. Can you live with the initial error? Can you calibrate the errors out to get better performance? Why can't use use digital components?

Comment: @Andyaka I can't use digital components because I am working on a pure analog project [Every thing is in the S-Domain]. No microcontrollers are used. PID is realized using opamps.

Comment: @Andyaka Using a cheap DC motor as a tachometer is a good idea. Thanks for suggesting it. I will look into it. I will also be interested to know about the other options available for measuring with less errors

Comment: But why does everything have to be analogue components? You haven't given a reason just a statement.

Comment: Because it is of the requirements of this project to not use any microcontrollers or digital controllers, and the whole system must be present in the s-domain, and processing must be done on Operational Amplifiers. If I use digital components like rotary encoders, I would not be able to realize a transfer function for them in the s-domain and I would not be able to process them with opamps.

Comment: Is it a college/school project where this constraint is set by a tutor?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's goal is to be very familiar with analog control before digital control

Comment: A toothed wheel or encoder and an integrator. Digital meets analog. Historically, tacho generators were generally used. These are effectively a small motor as Andy suggests. As for accuracy, how accurate do you want?

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion of an encoder and an integrator. It seems like the solution I am looking for. I am not looking for something really accurate, I just want something compact and easy to install on a motor. Just a simple setup.